# Insert a random string from a list into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to insert a random department name into an SQL Server table. Currently I have the code below. I want any of the four department values listed (comp sci, biology, psychology,chemistry) to be inserted randomly when I populate my table with sample data. Any help would be appreciated

```
Declare @SID int
Set @SID = 1

/* Create temporary table to insert random department name 
declare @myList table (Dept varchar(50))
insert into @myList values ('Computer Science'), ('Biology'), ('Psychology'), ('Chemistry')*/

While @SID <= 12000
Begin 
   Insert Into Student values ('Student', CAST(@SID as nvarchar(10)), 'Department' + CAST(@SID as nvarchar(10)), '50')
   Print @SID
   Set @SID = @SID + 1
End
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `select` (rather than `values`) to select from the list you have created and insert the `top 1` ordered by `newid()`.

```
   --insert into dbo.Student (Name, id, Department, Position)
   select top 1 'Student', CAST(@SID as nvarchar(10)), Dept, '50'
   from @myList
   order by newid();
```

Note: Its best practice to list all columns being inserted into.

Answer (score 1):

For TSQL, you can generate a random number, then use the first digit to determine which value to use, eg

```
declare @ran int = (select rand() * 10)

declare @subject varchar(100)=''

if @ran <= 3
   set @subject = 'computer science'
else if @ran <= 6
   set @subject = 'Biology'
else if @ran <= 8
   set @subject = 'Psychology'
else
   set @subject = 'Chemistry'

insert into table ...... etc etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you required 12,000 of random data, use `@myList` to `CROSS JOIN` itself. And use `row_number()` to generate the sequential number. The `random` part is handle by `NEWID()`

```
with stud as
(
    select  SID = row_number() over (order by newid()),
            l1.Dept
    from    @myList l1
            cross join @myList l2
            cross join @myList l3
            cross join @myList l4
            cross join @myList l5
            cross join @myList l6
            cross join @myList l7
)
select  *
from    stud
where   SID <= 12000
```

Comment: Where does `@myList` come from, maybe you want `(values (1),(1),(1)...`? And this doesn't give you random rownumbers, you need to order **the rownumber result** by `NEWID()`

Comment: `@myList` is from OP's query. random row_number is not the point here. The purpose is to randomize the dept

Comment: Kinda interesting thing to do, as then it doesn't stand on it's own. Best to use a `VALUES` clause. You need to select `CHECKSUM(NEWID())` to get a random rownumber